# How to compile a simple Arduino program?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am starting to learn / program the Arduino and I don't understand why I am getting syntax errors upon compiling my program in Visual Studio 2017 with Visual Micro or with the Arduino IDE.

### Compiling output error from Visual Studio 2017:

```
sketch\SketchIncomeEligible.ino.cpp.o:(.text.setup+0x0): undefined reference to `WiFi_Setup()'

sketch\SketchIncomeEligible.ino.cpp.o: In function `setup':

C:\Users\C113850\source\repos\Income_Eligible_Price_Display\src\SketchIncomeEligible\SketchIncomeEligible/SketchIncomeEligible.ino:6: undefined reference to `WiFi_Setup()'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266.
```

### Compiling error from Arduino IDE:

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266, 80 MHz, Flash, 4M (1M SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

sketch\SketchIncomeEligible.ino.cpp.o:(.text.setup+0x0): undefined reference to `WiFi_Setup()'

sketch\SketchIncomeEligible.ino.cpp.o: In function `setup':

C:\Users\C113850\source\repos\Income_Eligible_Price_Display\src\SketchIncomeEligible\SketchIncomeEligible/SketchIncomeEligible.ino:6: undefined reference to `WiFi_Setup()'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

The following is my code:

### SketchWiFi.h file:

```
#ifndef _SKETCHWIFI_h
#define _SKETCHWIFI_h

int WiFi_Setup();

#endif
```

### SketchWiFi.c file:

```
#include "SketchWiFi.h"

int WiFi_Setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  return 1; // Successful
}
```

### Sketch.ino file:

```
#include "SketchWiFi.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Begin setup");

  WiFi_Setup();

  Serial.println("End setup");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

**Directory structure:**

[image]

**Project Structure in Visual Studio 2017**

[image]

**Project structure in Arduino IDE**
[image]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: This might help you : https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Build-Process

Comment: You don't seem to use the Arduino IDE to compile your project.
How do you force `SketchWiFi.c` to be one of your source files ? Add a `SketchWiFi.cpp` to your project with that code.

Comment: are you using Arduino IDE to build?

Comment: Yes.  I have compiled in both environments, Visual Studio 2017 and Arduino IDE.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include screenshots of my project structure in Visual Studio 2017 and Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Per a suggestion posted, I read on GitHub the following:

**No pre-processing is done to files in a sketch with any extension other than .ino. Additionally, .h files in the sketch are not automatically #included from the main sketch file.** Further, if you want to call functions defined in a .c file from a .cpp file (like one generated from your sketch), you'll need to wrap its declarations in an 'extern "C" {}' block that is defined only inside of C++ files.

So that explains my problem.  I enclosed my simple function 'WiFi_Setup()' with in a class and now it compiles successfully.

```
class WifiNetwork
{
protected:

public:
    void WiFi_Setup();
};
```

It seems Arduino wants everything to live in classes.

Comment: could you show how the .h, and .c files were modified?